# Trouble mapping a win10 network drive - asking for my username and password which I don't have

Tags: windows, security, mapping

I'm getting frustrated by simply trying to map windows drives between my win11 and win10 machines. In both instances it's asking for my username and password, neither of which I know; I sign in with the PIN on both machines and am asked for neither. What am I missing here? I also can't figure out where to reset my password on either device. Sorry to be slow here but I've tried all I can think of and looked at numerous MS support sites. Thanks.